# React Router V6 - NotFound component not working with dynamic parameter/slug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have installed `"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0"` and created some page routes. Facing problems where the Page404 / NotFound component is not working if a page doesn't exist. For some reason when I am using dynamic page/post `slug` the component `NotFound` will not work if there is no page/post with this ID.

Is there an option inside React Router which solves this issue?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import AllPosts from "components/AllPosts";
import SinglePost from "components/SinglePost";
import NotFound from "components/Page404";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AllPosts />} path="/" exact />
      <Route element={<SinglePost />} path="/:slug" />
      <Route element={<NotFound />} path="*" />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Routes` and `Route` component can't possibly know ahead of time that some dynamic path, "/someUnsupportedIdValue" for example, isn't a valid path to be handled by `SinglePost`.

The options you have here are:

1. Conditionally render some alternative UI in `SinglePost`, something along the lines of "A page by this ID isn't found".
2. Check if a page with matching ID exists, conditionally render that page, or a redirect (`Navigate` component replaced `Redirect` in v6) to your more generic 404 page (actually, a redirect to any "throw away" path that isn't explicitly handled already will land you on your 404 page). Or you can imperatively redirect with a `navigate(to, { replace: true })`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove **exact** because was removed from v6 and make sure Page404 is the correct component or create **Notfound.jsx**
2. Check if the post not exists then redirect to Notfound page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).